# snprintf, for integer to string conversion in C

Tags: c, c-strings

I have a little piece of code to convert an integer to a string in c.
The code has to work on both 32-bits and 64 bits platform.

I am parsing arguments in a loop, so I need malloc to create the buffer

```
int tmp_integer = /*read as integer*/
char* tmp_string = malloc(20* sizeof(char)); /*enough room for the biggest integer*/
snprintf(tmp_string, 20,"%d",tmp_integer); /*can I avoid using 20 here*/
a[i - 1] = tmp_string; /*save the parsed argument for final usage*/
```

My question is :
Is there any way to make it nice using snprintf, or should I fall back to sprintf.

I figured that using snprintf was not the right thing to do, because originally I wanted to be protected from buffer overruns, but since the size of integer is known I think it is useless. Still I would like to know what is the best practice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in this case. You know your number is not bigger than 64bits, and you know that it means it won't have more than 20 digits. Therefore, you don't really need to use `snprintf`.

Bug: The biggest unsigned 64 bit number you can have is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 which is 20 digits. However, each string has a `'\0'` (`NUL`) character in the end (hence the nul-terminated string terminology). Therefore, you should allocate **21** bytes for your array and not 20.

Comment: I actually decided to go back to sprintf since, snprintf was not necessary in my case. And of course I didn't put a 21 in the code. It was here to ease the reading.

Comment: Great. In fact, `snprintf` comes in handy when you are dealing with strings. If not, there is always an easy to predict upper bound to the size of the buffer that could be computed and enough space allocated, so `sprintf` could be safely used. You may come across some people who stubbornly say "never use `sprintf`, always use `snprintf`". You can usually just ignore them

Comment: Yes I actually came to that conclusion hehe.

Answer (score 2):

If you allocate memory dynamically, you can use log10 to calculate the number of places needed in your string:

```
int tmp_integer = /*read as integer*/ 
int signpadding = 0;
if tmpinteger < 0 then signpadding = 1;
int digitcount = (integer)floor(log10(abs(value)))+ 1 + signpadding;
char* tmp_string = malloc(digitcount * sizeof(char)); 
snprintf(tmp_string, digitcount,"%d",tmp_integer);
```

Comment: It doesn't work for value = 0.
Plus, it's not even C or am I wrong? :)

Answer (score 1):

The question becomes where that magical "20" came from. Since it's magical, it should be represented as a symbolic constant, not an integer literal repeated in the code. Using a symbolic constant also has the benefit of having the compiler do the error-checking for you:

```
#define MAX_INTEGER_DIGITS (20)

int value = /* ... */
char* tmp_string = malloc(MAX_INTEGER_DIGITS);
snprintf(tmp_string, MAX_INTEGER_DIGITS, "%d", value);
```

(Also notice how I dropped the `sizeof (char)` thing, since it's totally redundant and (imo) very cluttering.)

From a performance point of view, you can probably do away with the protected variant of the string formatter, but since you're calling `malloc()` here anyway (not cheap) it's probably not a great win to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can sprintf in a temp buffer and then alloc the good size (with the return of sprintf), and then copy the temp into your buffer.

```
int tmp_integer = /*read as integer*/
static char tmp_string[20];
int size = sprintf(tmp_string,"%d",tmp_integer); 
char *myValueString = malloc((size+1)*sizeof(char));
a[i - 1] = strcpy(myValueString,tmp_string);
```

Comment: If all you need is the size of the result, you can `snprintf` to NULL with 0 size and look at its return value. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533556/how-do-i-use-strlen-on-a-formatted-string/10533616#10533616).

Answer (score 0):

This is another (maybe not so pretty) way to convert it based on [sum1stolemyname](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7793476/706098) code snippet:

```
char *convert_int_to_string(int value)
{
    int digitcount;
    char * tmp_string;
    int increment = 2; // one for rounding, one for '\0' terminator
    if(value <0){
            increment += 1; // make room for sign 
    }
    if(0 == value){
            tmp_string = malloc(2* sizeof(char));
            sprintf(tmp_string, "%u", 0);
    }
    else{
            digitcount = (int)floor(log10((double)abs(value)))+ increment;
            tmp_string = malloc(digitcount * sizeof(char));
            sprintf(tmp_string, "%d", value);
    }
    return tmp_string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple, portable (across various bitnesses, platforms and cpus) solution to this problem is:

```
int tmp_integer = /*read as integer*/
const size_t len = 4 * sizeof(int);
char tmp_string[len];
snprintf(tmp_string, len, "%d", tmp_integer);
```