# Function with string as return type

Tags: c, string, function, char, return-type

I wrote a function to print a float value neatly. At the moment it directly outputs it on screen, but somewhere else in my code I need to store the result of this function in a variable as string (or char[]). Any suggestion please?

```
void printfFloat(float toBePrinted)
{
    uint32_t fi, f0, f1, f2;
    char c;
    float f = toBePrinted;

    if (f<0)
    {
        c = '-';
        f = -f;
    }
    else
    {
        c = ' ';
    }

    // integer portion.
    fi = (uint32_t) f;

    // decimal portion...get index for up to 3 decimal places.
    f = f - ((float) fi);
    f0 = f*10;   f0 %= 10;
    f1 = f*100;  f1 %= 10;
    f2 = f*1000; f2 %= 10;
    if(c == '-')
        printf("%c%ld.%d%d%d", c, fi, (uint8_t) f0, (uint8_t) f1, (uint8_t) f2);
    else
        printf("%ld.%d%d%d", fi, (uint8_t) f0, (uint8_t) f1, (uint8_t) f2);
}
```

What should be return type of this function? I want at the end to do something like:

```
char[32] buffer;
buffer = printfFloat(_myFloat);
```

Comment: `malloc` a sufficiently large block of memory, and `sprintf` the value to that?

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you give some code please? no idea how to.

Comment: Why not just `printf("%.3f", f);` or am I missing something?

Comment: @meaning-matters Apparently to take of negative sign. This is for a micro-controller and its quite stupid

Comment: `%d` is the format specifier for `int` values. If you cast the parameters to smaller values it won't print correctly. Read up on format specifiers so you get what you want. I often use `%c, '0' + digit` to print a single digit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What should be return type of this function?

C does not have a String datatype, so you would have to pass the address of the buffer as a parameter:

```
char[32] buffer;
printfFloat(_myFloat, buffer);
```

Your function would become:

```
void printfFloat(float toBePrinted, char *buffer)
{
   ///rest of code

   if(c == '-')
    sprintf(buffer, "%c%ld.%d%d%d", c, fi, (uint8_t) f0, (uint8_t) f1, (uint8_t) f2);
   else
     sprintf(buffer, "%ld.%d%d%d", fi, (uint8_t) f0, (uint8_t) f1, (uint8_t) f2);
}
```

Comment: If you ever design such a function, please put a `max_len` parameter, and use `snprintf(buffer, max_len, ...)`. Otherwise you're just begging for a world of problems, because the function can have no idea where the buffer ends.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [asprintf](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/vsprintf/), it will allocate a buffer and fill it for you.

```
char *printfFloat(float toBePrinted)
{
    uint32_t fi, f0, f1, f2;
    char c;
    char *ret = NULL;
    float f = toBePrinted;

    if (f<0)
    {
        c = '-';
        f = -f;
    }
    else
    {
        c = ' ';
    }

    // integer portion.
    fi = (uint32_t) f;

    // decimal portion...get index for up to 3 decimal places.
    f = f - ((float) fi);
    f0 = f*10;   f0 %= 10;
    f1 = f*100;  f1 %= 10;
    f2 = f*1000; f2 %= 10;
    if(c == '-')
        asprintf(&ret, "%c%ld.%d%d%d", c, fi, (uint8_t) f0, (uint8_t) f1, (uint8_t) f2);
    else
        asprintf(&ret, "%ld.%d%d%d", fi, (uint8_t) f0, (uint8_t) f1, (uint8_t) f2);
    return ret;
}
```

In the main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char *ret = printfFloat(42.42);
   puts(ret); // print ret
   free(ret);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me please how to use it in main{} ?

Comment: @nouney, You forgot to free that memory.

Comment: `asprintf` is a GNU extension, not a standard C function.

Comment: @nouney hmmm asprintf isnt compiling...apparently does not exist in stdio.h

Comment: @Saei87 what's your OS and compiler ?

Comment: @Saeid87, instead of `asprintf`, you can find the length of the final string as explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10533616/912144), `malloc` enough memory and then `sprintf` in that.

Comment: @nouney I am working in ubuntu 12.04 and compiler is GCC 4.6.3 (for msp 430 microcontroller)

Comment: @Saeid87, yes I do. The first part (getting the length) is already in the other answer. There is a LOT on `malloc` in the man page or online. And everyone here told you about `sprintf`. Show some effort and put them together yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `sprintf` [function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/).

```
char buffer[32];
sprintf(buffer, "%f", your_float);
```